# Variable conversion mixup in C

Tags: c

I have the following C code and I have to understand why the result is a fairly big positive number:

```
int k;
unsigned int l;         
float f;
f=4; l = 1; k = -2; 
printf("\n %f", (unsigned int)l+k+f);
```

The result is a very large number (around 4 billion, max for 32 bit integers), so I suspect it has something to do with the representation of signed negative integers (two's complement) that looks fairly big if we look at it as unsigned.

However I don't quite understand why it behaves this way and what the float has to do with the behavior (if I remove it it stops doing it). Could someone explain how does it do that ? What is the process that happens when adding the numbers that leads to this result ?

Comment: look up type coercion in relation to `printf`

Comment: OP: **read** a good book on C. SO is not a 1 stop shop to post a question out of laziness on your part to do the research yourself and find out by reading the C standard, aka [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you add a signed `int` to an `unsigned`, C converts the result to an `unsigned int`, even negative ones. Since `k` is negative, it gets re-interpreted as a large positive number before the addition. After that the `f` is added, but it is small in comparison to negative 2 re-interpreted as a positive number.

Here is a short illustration of the problem:

```
int k = -2;
unsigned int l = 1;
printf("\n %u", l+k);
```

This prints `4294967295` on a 32-bit system, because `-2` in two's complement representation is `0xFFFFFFFE` ([demo](http://ideone.com/RYzAFa)).

Comment: Thanks, so the float actually makes no difference, that was confusing to me.

Comment: @user3604097 Float was important in your code, because it prevented undefined behavior that would otherwise result from printing an `unsigned` using `%f`.

Comment: I thought that the float had something to do with the incorrect conversion, that was confusing me. So it's entirely the -2 being directly converted to unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that when the compiler does the l+k it typecasts the k to unsigned int which turns it into that big number. If you change the order of the vars to this: l+f+k this behavior will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that a negative integer is converted to an `unsigned` integer by adding the maximum unsigned value, plus one, repeatedly to the signed value until it's representable.  This is why you see such a large value.

With two's complement, it's the same as truncating or sign extending the value and interpreting it as `unsigned` which is simple for a computer to do.